# Remote copy via SCP doesn't work in background

Tags: scp, nohup, nas, synology

**The situation:**

I'm switching file servers at home. I want to copy tons of data from one Synology Disk Station to another.

**My Approach:**

```
#Via SSH on the new server:
nohup scp -r ${old_server}:. .
```

I entered the credentials and closed my terminal emulator.

**The problem:**

I logged back in right again to see if it works. It began to copy files so I was satisfied.`ps aux | grep scp` showed the instance as well. Hence, I logged off and waited.

Two days later, I logged back in to have a look. And it seems like nothing has changed since the last time I logged in. `ps aux` still features the instance though.

Am I missing something? Why are the files not being copied in my absence?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Rather than a disowned or `nohup`ed `scp`, why not run (in a `screen` or `tmux` session) something like `rsync -essh -za user@host:/path/to/files /local/path/to/files`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Thank you for the comment, but what will that do for me? Do `screen` or `tmux` have the capability to run in the background without being attached to a terminal? I don't know these programs too well. And neither `tmux` nor `screen` are installed on the box. Issuing just the command returns: `rsync error: rsync service is no running (code 43) at io.c(687) [Receiver=3.0.9]`.

Comment: That is precisely what `screen` and `tmux` are _for_, actually.  As for the error with `rsync`, I don't believe you should have gotten that error if you had told it to use the secure shell backend with `-e ssh`.

Comment: @DopeGhoti I enabled rsync in the control panel of the Disk Station's web interface and now the command works. Yet I can't run it in background as I don't know any way to get `screen` or `tmux` on the box - except maybe compiling from source. And why does `nohup` not work as expected?